# inserting a new entry into adjacency list

Tags: python

I have an adjacency list maintained between 2 sets of entities

```
dict1={'x1':[y1,y2],'x2':[y2,y3,y4]...}
dict2={'y1':[x1],'y2':[x1,x2],'y3':[x2]....}
```

Given a new entry coming in ,what is the recommended way to update the dicts.
Assuming the entry is 'x3':[y2,y4].
Please note that x3 may not necessarily be a new vertex all the time.

Comment: Please make clear which dict you want to update and what should be the out come of update.

Comment: @user1943282 I think he wants to update both dicts as if they are two-way edges between the nodes

Comment: Its an adjacency list - so both dicts will get updated for any new entry that comes in.Obviously,it may be a new addition to the dicts or an update of any existing entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest `defaultdict` so that referencing an index that doesn't exist will initialize it to an empty list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = defaultdict(list)
dict1['x1'] = ['y1','y2']
dict1['x2'] = ['y2','y3','y4']
dict2 = defaultdict(list)
dict2['y1'] = ['x1']
dict2['y2'] = ['x1','x2']
dict2['y3'] = ['x2']
```

Then when `'x3':[y2,y4]` comes in:

```
dict1['x3'] = set(dict1['x3']+[y2,y4])
for y in dict1['x3']:
    dict2[y] = set(dict2[y]+'x3')
```

using `set` to eliminate duplicate values. Obviously some of the above values would be a little more dynamic than hard coded values.

Note: This isn't faster, in fact it's probably slower, but the defaultdict is a better way to avoid the KeyError and you definitely don't want to introduce duplicate values into your adj list as this will hurt the performance, or maybe even correctness, of whatever algorithm you apply to this graph.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do it in a simple way?

```
dict1[x3] = [y2, y4]
for yi in dict1[x3]:
    if yi in dict2.keys():
        dict2[yi].append(x3)
    else:
        dict2[yi] = [x3]
```

Comment: Needs something to handle IndexError for `yi` not in `dict2`

Comment: I can .For the new entry A,i would need to iterate dict1(and dict2) for the key;and thereafter i would need to do the same in the left-over dict for each of the values in A.Just needed to check if there is an elegant and faster way of achieving that

Comment: This will also potentially introduce repeat values

Comment: @Brian: How, given that `x3` is the new graph vertex?

Comment: @IUnknown: you don't iterate over a dict, you look up a value in it; and that's very fast in python

Comment: @AndreySobolev What precludes adding more adjacent vertices to an existing vertex?

Comment: Please note that x3 may not necessarily be a new vertex all the time.

Answer (score 0):

How about the `update()` function in the following code:

```
dict1={'x1':['y1','y2'],'x2':['y2','y3','y4']}

def mkdict2():
    dict2={}
    for x,ylist in dict1.items():
        for y in ylist:
            dict2[y] = list(dict2.get(y,[])) + [x]
    return dict2

dict2 = mkdict2()

print (dict1)
print (dict2)

def update(x,ylist):
    dict1[x] = list(dict1.get(x,[])) + ylist
    for y in ylist:
        dict2[y] = list(dict2.get(y,[])) + [x]

update('x3',['y2','y4'])

print (dict1)
print (dict2)
```

This gives the output:

```
 {'x1': ['y1', 'y2'], 'x2': ['y2', 'y3', 'y4']}
 {'y3': ['x2'], 'y2': ['x1', 'x2'], 'y1': ['x1'], 'y4': ['x2']}
 {'x1': ['y1', 'y2'], 'x2': ['y2', 'y3', 'y4'], 'x3': ['y2', 'y4']}
 {'y3': ['x2'], 'y2': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 'y1': ['x1'], 'y4': ['x2', 'x3']}
```

I'm always nervous about holding two data structures that contain the same data, in case they become inconsistent, hence my use of `mkdict2()` to generate `dict2` from `dict1` initially.